# How do I edit file name that same first word

Tags: bash

I have log files like this:

```
tmp_1_2_3_4_5.LOG
...
```

I need to change name like this:

```
1_2_3_4_5.LOG
```

I try:

```
rename 's/^tmp+_//' *
```

It's working on Debian, but not working on Red Hat. 
How can I do this with mv command?

Comment: just try: `rename 's/^tmp_//' *.LOG`

Comment: anubhava, not working.

Comment: Does rename command different on Red Hat? It's working on Debian, but does not on Red Hat. If I can't do this with rename, how can I do this with other command? Sed or mv etc... I need one line command for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, with mv :

```
for i in *; do s=$(sed -r 's/^(tmp_)(.*.LOG)/\2/' <<< $i); if [[ "$i" != "$s" ]]; then mv "$i" "$s"; fi; done;
```

Comment: It's working for all files, not just tmp_xxx_xxx.LOG. And said for other files: mv xx_xx.LOG and xx_xx.LOG are the same file.

Comment: u can ignore that, else i have edited my answer...

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a fairly simple for-loop:

```
for file in tmp_*; do
    [[ -e $file ]] || continue
    mv "$file" "./${file#tmp_}"
done
```

Also see [BashFAQ #30](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/030)